# scrape site after login

Tags: c#, web-scraping, webrequest

I'm trying to scrape a website that requires a login. Getting an error that I haven't received before, copied the code from another forum successfully in the past:

Exception Details: System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.

with the code:
Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream(); //open connection

Here's the entire code:

```
@{
    var strUserId = "userName";
    var strPassword = "password";
    var url = "formSubmitLandingSite";
    var url2 = "pageToScrape";
    HttpWebRequest http = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    http.KeepAlive = true;
    http.Method = "POST";
    http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string postData = "email=" + strUserId + "&password=" + strPassword;
    byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    http.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
    using (Stream postStream = http.GetRequestStream())
    {
        postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
    }
    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    // Probably want to inspect the http.Headers here first
    http = WebRequest.Create(url2) as HttpWebRequest;
    http.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    http.CookieContainer.Add(httpResponse.Cookies);
    HttpWebResponse httpResponse2 = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
    newStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length); // Send the data.
    newStream.Close();

    string sourceCode;
    HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    Response.Write(sourceCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new request object here:

```
http = WebRequest.Create(url2) as HttpWebRequest;
```

Keep in mind that the *default* HTTP verb used is `GET`.  Then you try to open the *request* stream here:

```
Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream();
```

This method is used to enable [writing data to the request's content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx).  However, `GET` requests don't *have* content.  As you do in the code above the error, you'll need to use a different HTTP verb.  `POST` is most common for this, and is what you're using above:

```
http.Method = "POST";
```

So just use a `POST` request again.  (Assuming, of course, that's what the server is expecting.  In any event, if the server is expecting *content* then it's definitely *not* expecting a `GET` request.)